Getting 404 on Express route when saving user
POST http://localhost:3000/auth/save-user 404 (Not Found)
    submitForm  @   signin.html:88
    onclick @   signin.html:58 

I am building a web site but I get this error in the sign in submit button. I want to save the user info in a json file but I get the save user was not found and the line is the fetch (link) but the link is correct. Code:
Html part:
// Send user data to backend using fetch
fetch('http://localhost:3000/auth/save-user', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(userData),
})

auth js part:
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

// Path to users.json
const usersFilePath = path.join(__dirname, "users.json");

// POST route to save a user
router.post("/save-user", (req, res) => {
  const userData = req.body;

  // Validate input data
  if (!userData.name || !userData.email || !userData.password) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: "All fields are required" });
  }

  // Read the users file
  fs.readFile(usersFilePath, "utf8", (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).json({ message: "Error reading users file" });
    }

    const users = JSON.parse(data || "[]"); // Parse existing users or initialize as empty array

    // Check if user already exists
    const userExists = users.some((user) => user.email === userData.email);
    if (userExists) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: "User already exists" });
    }

    // Add the new user to the list
    users.push(userData);

    // Write updated data back to users.json
    fs.writeFile(usersFilePath, JSON.stringify(users, null, 2), (err) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({ message: "Error saving user" });
      }

      // Respond with success
      res.status(200).json({ message: "User saved successfully!" });
    });
  });
});
// Export router
module.exports = router;

I have checked the link and the way its been passed to the js file but nothing. Can someone help with this?

Is there any Java code or did you mean JavaScript?

You have checked the link, so what? Is it ok?

Did you register the `router?

show the code where you mount the router in app.js (it should be something like app.use('/auth', auth);)

Why the error return?
Your code is trying to send data to http://localhost:3000/auth/save-user, but the server doesn’t know what to do with that request. This happens because:

The server doesn’t know about your /auth/save-user route.
The server might not be running.
The fetch URL or route setup might be wrong.

We have to some common solutions for solve to this issue look at bellow steps,

Connect the Route in Your Main Server File Open your main server
file (usually called server.js or app.js) and make sure you’ve
connected your auth.js file to the server. try to use bellow code,
const express = require("express");
const authRouter = require("./auth"); // Path to your auth.js file
const app = express();
app.use(express.json()); // Helps the server read JSON data from requests
app.use("/auth", authRouter); // Use the routes in auth.js for /auth
app.listen(3000, () => {
console.log("Server is running on http://localhost:3000");
});

Make Sure the File users.json Exists If the users.json file
doesn’t exist, create it in the same folder as auth.js and add an
empty array inside:

Check the Fetch URL In your HTML file, the fetch function should
point to http://localhost:3000/auth/save-user. Double-check the
URL is correct.


Example code,
fetch('http://localhost:3000/auth/save-user', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(userData), // Replace userData with your actual user data
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => console.log(data)) // Check the response in your browser console
.catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));


Start the Server Make sure your server is running. Open your terminal, go to the folder where your server.js file is, and run:
node server.js


5.If its still doesn't work add bellow code and console log your issue and mention it here,
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(`Received ${req.method} request for ${req.url}`);
    next();
});

